# ¿Como puedo solucionar el error de pd en jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hola me podrian ayudar con el error de pd en jupyter notebook

en la imagen ingreso pandas o pd y en ambos me figura error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, estas importando `pandas` con el sobrenombre `pd`, debe ser `pd.read_csv`.

Comment: correcto ingreso df = pd.read_csv.... e igual me arroja error

Comment: ya intentaste volver a ejecutar el bloque de los import antes de ejecutar el bloque de pd.read_csv?

Answer (score 1):

Primero ejecuta la celda anterior para que el notebook detecte el código.
Una vez ejecutado el mismo ya padras ejecutar la celda que da error.
Suerte!!

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).